# Wierd behaviour using a service manager invokable

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm still learning to understand ZF2 and imho the best way is by doing things. I came across this wierd issue and was wondering if this is expected behaviour.

In my application i have the following codes

```php
//In module.php getServiceConfig()
return array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'hardwareEntity'        => 'Hardware\Model\Hardware',
    ),
}
```

in my controller i retrieve data from a blob of text which results in a array of x elements let's take 3 for the example

```php
$hardwares = array(
    'hw1' => array(
        'name'  => 'router1'
        'ip'    => '192.168.0.200',
        'type'  => 'router',
    ),

    'hw2' => array(
        'name'  => 'pc1'
        'ip'    => '192.168.0.210',
        'type'  => 'pc',
    ),

    'hw3' => array(
        'name'  => 'pc2'
        'ip'    => '192.168.0.211',
        'type'  => 'pc',
    ),
);
```

i have a hardware class in the hardware module

```php
namespace Hardware\Model\;
class Hardware
{
    protected $name = null;
    protected $ip   = null;
    protected $type = null;

    public function exchangeArray(array $data) {

        $this->name = (isset($data['name']))    ? $data['name'] : $this->name;
        $this->ip   = (isset($data['ip']))      ? $data['ip']   : $this->ip;
        $this->type = (isset($data['type']))    ? $data['type'] : $this->type;
    }
}
```

Ok the magic comes when i do the following foreach loops i get different results

```php
foreach($hardwares as $hw) {
    $h = $this->getServiceManager()->get('hardwareEntity');
    $h->exchangeData($hw);
    $aObjects[] = $h
}
```

the $aObjects array now contains 3 elements with objects with the type of Hardware\Model\Hardware, but with the data of the last $hardwares element (aka it overwrites all the classes with the data while looping)

RESULT:

```php
array(3) {
    [0]=> 
    object(Hardware\Model\Hardware)#219 {
        ["name":protected]=>
        string(7) "pc2"
        ["ip":protected]=>
        string(13) "192.168.0.211"
        ["type":protected]=>
        string(6) "pc"
    }
    [1]=> 
    object(Hardware\Model\Hardware)#219 {
        ["name":protected]=>
        string(7) "pc2"
        ["ip":protected]=>
        string(13) "192.168.0.211"
        ["type":protected]=>
        string(6) "pc"
    }
    [2]=> 
    object(Hardware\Model\Hardware)#219 {
        ["name":protected]=>
        string(7) "pc2"
        ["ip":protected]=>
        string(13) "192.168.0.211"
        ["type":protected]=>
        string(6) "pc"
    }
```

But when i do

```php
foreach($hardwares as $hw) {
    $h = new \Hardware\Model\Hardware();
    $h->exchangeData($hw);
    $aObjects[] = $h
}
```

it fills the $aObjects array with newly instantiated classes that contain different data each.

RESULT:

```php
array(3) {
    [0]=> 
    object(Hardware\Model\Hardware)#219 {
        ["name":protected]=>
        string(7) "router1"
        ["ip":protected]=>
        string(13) "192.168.0.200"
        ["type":protected]=>
        string(6) "router"
    }
    [1]=> 
    object(Hardware\Model\Hardware)#220 {
        ["name":protected]=>
        string(7) "pc1"
        ["ip":protected]=>
        string(13) "192.168.0.210"
        ["type":protected]=>
        string(6) "pc"
    }
    [2]=> 
    object(Hardware\Model\Hardware)#221 {
        ["name":protected]=>
        string(7) "pc2"
        ["ip":protected]=>
        string(13) "192.168.0.211"
        ["type":protected]=>
        string(6) "pc"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [service manager quick start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html#using-configuration)

> shared, an array of service name/boolean pairs, indicating whether or not a service should be shared. By default, the ServiceManager assumes all services are shared, but you may specify a boolean false value here to indicate a new instance should be returned.

So you probably need to do something like this...

```
//In module.php getServiceConfig()
return array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'hardwareEntity'        => 'Hardware\Model\Hardware',
    ),
    'shared' => array(
         'hardwareEntity' => false,
    ),
}
```

Comment: Holy moly that did the trick. I'm still a bit confused by the terminology. But thanks

Comment: Confused me a bit at first, but basically service manager services are a bit like singletons, you always get the same instance back, unless you tell it explicitly not to share that service instance. When you do that it behaves more like a factory method.